# Drush sql-dump with stored procedures

Tags: database, drush

According to the current documentation I don't think this is possible, or is it? 
(`drush sql-dump --routines` doesn't work or anything like that)

Aaaannndd... let's say it's not possible, and I want to add this feature to drush sql-dump command, how can I do that? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working for MySQL with the `extra` option:

```
$> drush sql-dump --extra="--routines"
```

References:

- Drush command: https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/sql/sql-dump/
- MySQL dump options: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html